# Delete all core data records does not set hasChanges in managedContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am new to coreData, and I have a problem:

My app executes the following 3 successive core data functions:

```
    let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    deleteAllCDRecords(managedContext: managedContext, in: "CDShoppingItem")
    saveManagedContext(managedContext: managedContext)
```

They are defined (shortened) as:

```
private func deleteAllCDRecords(managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext, in entity: String) {
    let deleteFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: deleteFetch)
    do {
        try managedContext.execute(deleteRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // error handling
    }
} // deleteAllCDRecords
```

and

```
private func saveManagedContext(managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    if !managedContext.hasChanges { return }
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // error handling
    }
} // saveManagedContext
```

**The problem:**

After `deleteAllCDRecords` is executed, `managedContext.hasChanges` in function `saveManagedContext` **is not true**, thus the deletion is not saved to the persistent store.

**My question:**
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Batch deletes operate in the persistent store itself. So in this special case you delete the entities from the persistent store and have to remove the objects in memory afterwards.

> Batch deletes run faster than deleting the Core Data entities yourself
>   in code because they operate in the persistent store itself, at the
>   SQL level. As part of this difference, the changes enacted on the
>   persistent store are not reflected in the objects that are currently
>   in memory.
>
> After a batch delete has been executed, remove any objects in memory
>   that have been deleted from the persistent store.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html.